# Disable function (existing) if class name exists

Tags: jquery

Want to disable function if class name exists for particular container.  Used below code.

```
if($("testElement1").hasClass("Content")){
   !testFunction();
}
else{

}
```

Want to add inside (Existing code)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  testFunction();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood what you're trying to achieve, you just need to invert the logic in the `if` condition:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    // if test element *does not* have the class 'Content'
    if (!$("testElement1").hasClass("Content")) 
        testFunction();
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. i missed this logic.